# WPF RichTextBox increase grid row size

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the following XAML

```
<Grid>
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>  <!--Here Expander with RichTextBox within-->
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>  <!--Here Splitter-->
      <RowDefinition Height="*"/>     <!--Here some other controls-->
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>
...
```

The problem is when Expander open and RichTextBox fills with text rows it automatically increase its heigth as well as expander and grid row height, That way items on bottom row sliding down.

I want to have bottom grid row height to be independent from richtextbox. Can I do it without binding RichTextBox height to the Expander or top row height?

Thank you.

Comment: Right now you've configured the top two rows to take as much height as they need and you've told the bottom row to take whatever space is left.  It sounds like you just need to give the RichTextBox a specific height or a max height so that it doesn't get too big.

Comment: On middle row I have splitter for user to have option to resize bottom and top row as he pleases. That way top and bottom grid rows may not have fixed maximum sizes. I have to configure top row height as "Auto" because it based on expader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. I found best solution by myself.

I reworked xaml that way:

```
<Grid>
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Name="TopRow" Height="42"/>  <!--Here Expander with RichTextBox within-->
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>  <!--Here GridSplitter-->
      <RowDefinition Height="*"/>     <!--Here some other controls-->
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>
...
```

At the start `Expander` always collapsed.
42 is a height of `Expander` on collapsed state.
`GridSplitter` considered to have `Visibility.Collapsed` at the start.

So I have created two triggers for expander:

- OnExpanded set `TopRow.Height = 160` and `GridSplitter.Visibility =
  Visibility.Expanded`
- OnCollapsed set `TopRow.Height = 42` and    `GridSplitter.Visibility
  = Visibility.Collapsed`

In stead of 160 I will use old row height (before collapsion). That's it. Everything work fine it seems.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could add one more  Row to the Grid, and define a `MinHeight` for that Row.
 Set your DataGrid Vertical alignment to stretch  `VerticalAlignment = Stretch`. Also set a default height size for the Window.

Comment: Where should I add new row? I do not quite understand. I do not have DataGrid but have Grid.

Comment: You could set the minimum height of each row

Comment: Yes I can but it will not prevent bottom row sliding to its minimum height. I guess sliding is not the userfriendy feature as such. Can i totally avoid sliding effect? I can't predict minimum height of each row since there is Splitter exists.